# Riemann Integrability in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, riemann-sum

Define the *General Subdivision* $S$ of a rectangle $R$ in $\Bbb R^2$ as a collection $E_1,...,E_k$ of Jordan regions such that none of them has interior points in common, and:

$$R \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k E_i$$

The *norm of $S$* is defined as:

$$d(S)=\max \left[\operatorname{diam}(E_i:1<i<k)\right]$$

Where $diam$ denotes denotes the diameter of each rectangle. Also, if $f$ is a continuous in $R$ and for each $i$, $(x_i, y_i)$ is in $E_i$ then the sum

$$S(f,S,(x_i,y_i))= \sum_{i=i}^k f(x_i,y_i)  \operatorname{vol}(E_i)
$$

is named the *Riemann sum of $f$ in S*. I need to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $d(S)<\delta$ then:

$$\left| \iint_R f \ dA -S(f,S,(x_i,y_i)) \right| < \epsilon $$

The definition of integral I've been studying is given by the superior and inferior sums:

$$\iint_R f \ dA= \sup \{L(f,P) \mid \text {P is a partition of } \mathbb{R}\}= \inf \{ U(f,P) \mid \text {P is a partition of } \mathbb{R} \}$$

I tried using the Cauchy Criterion but i couldn't prove what I need. Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume $f$ is integrable, hence, bounded on the compact rectangle $R \subset \Bbb R^2$.

If $I$ is the integral, then for any $\epsilon > 0 $, there is a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that $U(f,P_\epsilon) < I + \epsilon/4$. (The integral is the infimum of upper sums).

A partition can be characterized as the collection of vertices $(x_i,y_j)$ that form non-overlapping sub-rectangles $[x_{i-1},x_i] \times [y_{j-1},y_j]$ covering R:

$$P_{\epsilon} = \{(x_i,y_j): 0 \leq i \leq M, 0 \leq j \leq N, R = \cup_{i = 1}^M \cup_{j = 1}^N[x_{i-1},x_i] \times [y_{j-1},y_j]\}.$$

Let

$$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4MNDd(R)}$$

where $D = \sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|:x,y \in  R \}$ denotes the maximum oscillation of $f$,   $MN$ is the number of sub-rectangles in the partition $P_\epsilon$, and $d(R)$ is the diameter of $R$.

Now let $P$  be *any* partition with $d(P)<\delta$.

Form the common refinement $Q$ of $P$ and $P_{\epsilon}.$ Each sub-rectangle of $P$ and $P_{\epsilon}$ is a finite union of sub-rectangles of $Q$. The upper and lower sums of a partition bracket the sums for a refined partition:

$$L(f,P_{\epsilon}) \leqslant L(f,Q) \leqslant U(f,Q) \leqslant U(f,P_{\epsilon}), \\ L(f,P) \leqslant L(f,Q) \leqslant U(f,Q) \leqslant U(f,P). $$

Each sub-rectangle $R_{ij}$ of $P$ is of the form

$$R_{ij} = [x_{i-1}^P,x_i^P] \times [y_{j-1}^P,y_j^P]$$

and can be decomposed as a union of sub-rectangles $R_{ijkl} \subset R_{ij}$ of $Q$:

$$R_{ij} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{m_{ij}} \bigcup_{l=1}^{n_{ij}} R_{ijkl}.$$

The upper sums $U(f,P)$ and $U(f,Q)$ are

$$U(f,P) = \sum_{i,j} \sup_{x \in R_ij} f(x) vol(R_ij), \\ U(f,Q) = \sum_{i,j}\sum_{k,l} \sup_{x \in R_{ijkl}} f(x) vol(R_{ijkl}).$$

As $R_{ijkl} \subset R_{ij}$, we have

$$\sup_{x \in R_{ij}}f(x)-\sup_{x \in R_{ijkl}}f(x) \leqslant D.$$

Hence,

$$U(f,P) - U(f,Q) \leqslant \sum_{i,j}\sum_{k,l} [\sup_{x \in R_{ij}}f(x)-\sup_{x \in R_{ijkl}}f(x) ]vol(R_{ijkl}) \leqslant D\sum_{i,j}\sum_{k,l} vol(R_{ijkl}). $$

Each sub-rectangle $R_{ijkl}$ of $Q$ is of the form

$$R_{ijkl} = [x_{k-1}^{(i)},x_k^{(i)}] \times [y_{l-1}^{(j)},y_l^{(j)}], \\ vol(R_{ijkl}) = (x_{k}^{(i)}-x_{k-1}^{(i)})(y_{l}^{(j)}-y_{l-1}^{(j)}).  $$

We formed the common refinement $Q$ from $P$ and $P_{\epsilon}$ (with $MN$ sub-rectangles). The partition $Q$ has no more than $MN$ more partition points  than $P,$ in either dimension.

Hence,

$$U(f,P) - U(f,Q)  \leqslant D\sum_{i,j}\sum_{k,l} vol(R_{ijkl}) \\ = D\sum_{i}\sum_{j} \sum_{k} \sum_{l }(x_{k}^{(i)}-x_{k-1}^{(i)}) (y_{l}^{(j)}-y_{l-1}^{(j)}) \\ =D\sum_{i}\sum_{k} (x_{k}^{(i)}-x_{k-1}^{(i)}) \sum_{j} \sum_{l } (y_{l}^{(j)}-y_{l-1}^{(j)}) \\ \leqslant D\sum_{i}\sum_{k} (x_{k}^{(i)}-x_{k-1}^{(i)}) d(R) \\ \leqslant D(MN \delta) d(R).$$

Substituting for $\delta$ we find

$$U(f,P) - U(f,Q) \leqslant MND d(R)\delta= \epsilon/4.$$

It follows that

$$U(f,P) \leqslant U(f,Q) + \epsilon/4 \\ <  U(f,P_\epsilon)+\epsilon/4 \\  < I + \epsilon/2.$$

By a similar argument, you can show $L(f,P)> I - \epsilon/2$.

If $S(f,P)$ is any Riemann sum with respect to the partition P, then

$$I - \epsilon/2 < L(f,P) \leqslant S(f,P) \leqslant U(f,P) < I + \epsilon/2,$$

and

$$|S(f,P) - I| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: I´m sorry, what is $Q$?

Comment: Oh! think I saw it; $Q=P_e \cup P$ right?

Comment: We merge the partitions $P_{\epsilon}$ and $P$ to form $Q$. Every rectangle in $Q$ is a subset of rectangles in the courser partitions.

Comment: A rectangle $R_i$ in a partition in $R^2$ is of the form $R_i = [x_{j-1},x_j] \times [y_{k-1},y_k]$.  So the sets of the $x$ and $y$ end points that form $Q$ contain comparable sets for $P$ and $P_{\epsilon}.$ So $Q = P_{\epsilon} \cup P$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ partition points -- not rectangles.

Comment: To show that $L(f,P)> I - \epsilon/2$ should I use the fact that $L(f,P_{\epsilon})>I-\epsilon / 4$ or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes we can find $L(f,Q) > L(f,P_{\epsilon})>I-\epsilon / 4$ and $-\epsilon/4 < L(f,P) - L(f,Q) < \epsilon/4 \implies L(f,P)> L(f,Q) - \epsilon/4.$

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez: I hope this helps.  This is actually an important result in Riemann integration. Textbooks generally go one way or the other in defining the integral: $|S(P,f) - I| < \epsilon$ if (1) $P$ is  refinement of $P_{\epsilon}$ or (2) $||P|| < \delta$ -- without showing the equivalence of (1) and (2).

Comment: Which part is unclear or lacking the details you are looking for?

Comment: I don´t understand very well your choice of $\delta$ and how you bound the contributions of $R'$, any help will be rewarded :)

Comment: Why is it that $vol(R')D< D\delta^2$ ?

Comment: I added further details to the answer. The volume of any sub-rectangle in $Q$ is less than the volume of any sub-rectangle of $P$ that contains it.  The volume of any sub-rectangle of $P$ must be less than or equal to $\delta^2$.

Comment: You've been really helpful, thanks a lot! I can`t give you the bounty points to you yet (I have to wait 20 hours) , but you surely earned them.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez: Thanks very much.

Comment: I have a simplification where $\delta = \epsilon/(4Dd(R)max(M,N))$. Ill update tomorrow

Comment: @RRL The general region $E_i$ is no necessarily a rectangle. How do you know that a partition $P$ with $d(P) \lt \delta$ works for these regions? I am just confussed because Riemann sums uses rectangles all the time, and the Riemann sum specified in the question uses $vol(E_i)$

Comment: In the question it is stated that $R$ is a rectangle.  There is some confusing wording about the nature of $E_i$.  It is described as a Jordan region first and then referred to as a rectangle in the definition of $d(S)$. Also $S$ seems to be used to denote both the sum and the partition. Just look past of all of that. In my proof, I only consider partitions into sub-rectangles as is the usual approach for constructing Riemann integrals.  This is really about proving the equivalence of the two ways of defining the integral: with Darboux sums and with Riemann sums.

Comment: @mate89: Aside from my previous comment, just assume that OP meant for $E_i$ to be a rectangle as it should be in defining the integral.